# Resources and examples for developing games on the iPhone

Tags: iphone

All,

I'm about to embark on the adventure of developing a game for the iPhone. I have never programmed games before, and have never used Objective-C either - it's all new. I have, however, done sufficient amount of programming (C# recently, C long ago) and am comfortable with programming, frameworks, SDK/API etc.

What resources would you recommend for a newbie game developer? Let's just assume my first game is only to learn basics of game programming and getting my hands dirty on Objective-C.

Any points, resources, book references, tutorials etc. much appreciated.

-Adarsh

Answer (score 0):

[iCodeBlog](http://icodeblog.com/category/iphone-game-programming/) has some tutorials on how to make some simple games on the iPhone. Getting to know Objective C is also essential. Even though the iCodeBlog tutorials are simple you should also familiarize yourself with the language, eg. by reading Apples [Objective C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).

Happy coding